# Create PDF from html page using spring boot

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, pdf

I have project based on spring boot. which create salary slip for employee dynamically, now i want to convert that salary slip which is html page to PDF and push it to my server folder. i have done this with JQuery.

My question is:
1] can i push PDF created by JQuery on server?
2] Or any java library to convert that html to PDF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Library Flying Saucer for this.
In your spring based project add the following dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Upload the html file through POST and use this library's functions to convert in into pdf

You can read about Flying Saucer [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use $.ajax to upload

JS:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', pdfFile);
$.ajax({
  url: path/to/upload
  data: form_data,
  processData: false
})
```

Java:

```
public void uploadPdf(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile pdfFile)
```

2. You can try wkhtmltopdf (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)